# frontier_exploration to do unbounded exploration

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the frontier_exploration [indigo]. I had troubles to use it, but now I know how to use it with limited settings.
What I really want to do is the unbounded exploration. The wiki reads
"To run an unbounded exploration task, simply leave the boundary blank."
I don't know what this means.
When I set polygon regions using "Publish Points" in rviz, the robot seemed to stop even though there are unknown regions, saying "Finished exploration room" message.
Could you help me run the unbounded exploration?

Here are my settings:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)
- Turtlebot gazebo simulator
- Gmapping for map building
- ROS: Indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204382/frontier_exploration-to-do-unbounded-exploration/) by [JollyGood](https://answers.ros.org/users/985/jollygood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2015-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [syafiqsalam](https://answers.ros.org/users/22212/syafiqsalam/) on 2015-04-19**:
can i apply into hydro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To do 'unbounded' exploration, you send an actionlib goal (either using a SimpleActionClient implementation, or by running actionlib's axclient.py) that contains an empty polygon.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on 2017-03-23**:
Hello , I have written a python code for sending empty polygon. But the turtlebot doesnt move . Can you help us with a code ? I am not sure how to use axclient.py either . Please help

**Comment by [useranonymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/26258/useranonymous/) on 2017-07-30**:
rosrun actionlib axclient.py /explore_server

**Comment by [hasnain](https://answers.ros.org/users/33864/hasnain/) on 2018-03-26**:
does unbounded mean that it will start moving on its own and autonomously map the environment?